# Как в EasyAdmin 3 добавить запись в 2 сущности в одном контроллере?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

Подскажите пожалуйста куда смотреть и возможно ли в EasyAdmin 3 чтобы в одном контроллере при добавлении записи в сущность некоторые данные записывались еще и в другую сущность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все возможно, смотри в сторону коллекций в формах, да и в принципе для адекватной работы с easy admin надо в формах шарить хоть немного. Плюс никто не отменял кастомных form type с абсолютно любым поведением на ваш вкус